# Some doubts about how computers turn binary into audio

Tags: audio

I am not sure whether if I posted this to the right place or if this should be in StackOverflow, since I want to use this knowledge for programming.

Ok so I don't know much about acoustics...

I know that with uncompressed images like bitmaps each pixel has 3 bytes: 1 for red, 1 for green and 1 for blue

But how does audio work? 
I used a program to generate all numbers from 0 to 255 and to 0 again, pasted these in a file using HxD, saved it with no extention and then imported the raw to Audacity and this is what it looks like:

[image: image in Audacity]

Now, my questions:

1. Why are some below the 0 horizontal line and others above? What does that line stand for?
2. Why doesn't the picture look like a triangle, since it goes from 0 to 255 to 0? Why does it look so weird?

After some thinking I think I have figured some stuff out:
The place where that horizontal and vertical lines intercept is the middle of the graph/file and therefore it should be 255. Also, those peaks between 0,001 and 0,002 and between 0,004 and 0,005 look like a break in the graph, like it continues on the correspondent peaks below the horizontal line. Am I close?

Also, I wonder what those irregularities at the end and the begining, after and before the aforementioned peaks respectively, are. I suspect Audacity uses some mathematical function to get the points in their correct place for audio and that function has sines or other trigonometric operations. I read somewhere that sines and cosines have something to do with sound.

I also have some doubts about keys (E,F,C,etc...). Do they have something to do with the pitch? What are they exactly?

EDIT: I realized I made a really dumb mistake when generating the dots for the graph. Basically I forgot to add a 0 before every number below 16 and so when my input to the file were the bytes, for example, 1,2,3 and 4 and would end up getting written to the file would be the 2 bytes 12 and 34. Anyways I fixed it and those "interferences" in the begining and end dissapeared.
This is what the graphs of 0-255-0, 0-255 and 255-0 look like, for comparison:
http://postimg.org/image/nmoq9mmdp/

Comment: Software converts the bits into audio, depending on what container or codec that is used how the software handles the bits. Its a complex subject too large for SU.

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be noted that *some* image container types (like [bmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap)) have 3 byte values to represent red, green and blue values, others can have 4 byte values for red, green, blue and the alpha channel. Others can have more.

This is just how we use computers to represent visual information; this is because if you were to take a snapshot and translate it's "raw" values into bytes, the actual amount of bytes would be quite substantial (in the GB+ range for a 5"x7" image if the full spectrum is used). So we use algorithms and hardware techniques to trick our brains into thinking we are seeing a full color representation of an image when being presented it digitally.

> I read somewhere that sines and cosines have something to do with sound.

Audio is different because there is substantially less physical information for audio. [Sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound) (like light), is a wave (which can be easily represented by a sine/cosine function). Where light is an electrical wave, sound is a physical wave. Light is produced at an atomic level and the passing of electrons releases photons; light waves are bit more complex to turn into raw digital information than sound is. Sound is produced when molecules and atoms bump into each other. This physical pressure is relatively easy to turn from a physical wave, into an electrical wave with magnets and coils (much like a microphone operates). Taking this electrical signal (`+/- V`), we can then turn it into a digital signal (`1`/`0`) to represent the physical sound wave. Raw audio takes up much less space than visual does but still well more than we have current hard drive space (my 50k+ MP3 collection would take orders of magnitude more space if they were raw audio).

This digital signal that represents the audio waveform must now some how be rendered so that it can be used or played back, since if you just took the raw audio bytes and "played" them at the speed of your CPU, it would more than likely sound like a loud blip or some other random sound. To this, the waveform must be sampled at evenly timed intervals representing each interval as a number. Those numbers are the bytes, the 0-255 you are changing, they are what represent the audio waveform and represent such things as frequency and volume (assuming a raw audio format and not a container like an `mp3` or `aac`).

As one comment pointed out, this specific answer can be somewhat complex (given what you are asking and what needs to be explained for sufficient understanding), so whether asked here or on SO, I'd recommend taking a look at [`Digital Audio Fundamentals`](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/digital_audio.html) from the Audacity manual. It has a good primer on what you're asking and might get your further than could be reasonably explained through one of these forums.

I'd be happy to expand more (here or on SO) if you have questions after digging through some of their documentation. Hope that can help.